# Generating transformation matrix for 2D camera with pan/zoom/rotate

Tags: 2d, camera, lua, transformation, love2d

## Question

How do you implement a camera with pan/zoom/rotation for a 2d game? Is it acceptable to multiply together a series of transformation matrixes to generate a final transformation matrix that is applied to the vectors/vertices in a scene, or is there a more efficient way?

## Overview

Working on a 2d game in [löve2d](http://love2d.org/) I recently tried implementing a camera class that allows for panning/rotation/scrolling.

I tried finding a good resource for how to implement such a 2d camera, but was unable to find one that covered all three degrees of movement, and so I came up with my own solution.

I would like some feedback on if this is a good approach, and how it could be optimized/improved upon.

## My Attempt

My camera object stores the following values:

1. *position*: (`Vector2`)(World-Space position relative to the origin)
2. *angle*: (`float`)(how much the world is rotated, in radians)
3. *zoom*: (`float`)(the zoom factor, 1 = normal, 0.5 = 2x zoom, etc)
4. *offset_center*: (`Vector2`)(center the camera on the point of rotation using `[screen_width/2,screen_height/2]`)
5. *offset*: (`Vector2`)(any additional offset away from the center of rotation, typically just `[0,0]`

Whenever a camera value changes (basically each frame) I run `camera:computeMatrix()` which calculates its transformation matrix:

```
Camera.computeMatrix = function (self)

    local m_pos = Matrix{ -- World-space Position
        {1, 0, self.position.x},
        {0, 1, self.position.y},
        {0, 0, 1}
    }

    local m_zoom = Matrix{ -- Zoom
        {self.zoom, 0, 0},
        {0, self.zoom, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1}
    }

    local m_rot = Matrix{ -- Rotation
        {math.cos(self.angle), math.sin(self.angle), 0},
        {-math.sin(self.angle), math.cos(self.angle), 0},
        {0, 0, 1}
    }

    local m_offset = Matrix{ -- Screen-space Offset
        {1, 0, self.offset_center.x + self.offset.x},
        {0, 1, self.offset_center.y + self.offset.y},
        {0, 0, 1}
    }

    self.matrix = nil
    -- reverse order than when applying them 1 by 1
    self.matrix =  m_offset * m_rot * m_zoom * m_pos
end
```

So once `Camera.matrix` is calculated as a 3x3 matrix, I apply that to a given vertex/vector:

```
Vector2.TransformM = function (v, m)
    -- m is a 3x3 matrix of format {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
    return Vector2(v.x*m[1][1]+v.y*m[1][2]+m[1][2], v.x*m[2][2]+v.y*m[2][2]+m[2][3])
end
```

An example of this implementation:

[image: Screenshot]

[Download](https://copy.com/HoLebyEwkOLtV2JW) (pan with WASD, rotate with Q/E, zoom with 1/2)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I should probably clarify that... Basically I'd like to know how you would handle a 2d camera with pan/rotation/zoom in a 2d game. It seems to me that the way I'm generating the transformation matrix might not be ideal.

Comment: You could do it this way. Your interface deals with vectors and scalars instead of matrices. This is probably more natural for a 2D game. You could have the interface use more matrices instead. This way you just multiply your existing transform by a new matrix, instead of changing position vectors and scale floats. This probably belongs on Code Review more, though.

Comment: Have you looked at [hump.camera](http://vrld.github.io/hump/#hump.camera)? If you just want the functionality then you could use that (it's simple to use and it's working for me). If you want to write your own camera, take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/camera.lua) for ideas.

Comment: @NauticalMile Yep, I actually stumbled upon this myself looking at the love.graphics coordinate system methods, which it turns out is what hump.camera seems to be using. The result runs about 3-5 times faster than my hardcoded transformation matrixes :) https://copy.com/uTmUCRkIhrQeqr2g

Comment: @Johannes Based on comments, you seem to have found a solution. Could you post it as an answer for future visitors to refer to? (It's totally OK to add your own answer and accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late answer - I originally jumped on the love IRC where I was pointed towards [love.graphics's Coordinate Functions](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics#Coordinate_System) which allows you to modify love's coordinate system to do exactly what I wanted. Credit also to [NauticaMile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/34569/nauticalmile) for suggesting [hump.camera](http://vrld.github.io/hump/#hump.camera), which uses this as the underlying implementation.

This example replaces my original hardcoded transformation matrices with the relevant love.graphics functions. Using this my original program ended up being 3-5 times faster, but it could certainly be more optimized:

```
-- CANVAS METHODS --
Camera.attach = function (self)
    local cx, cy = love.graphics.getWidth()/(2*self.scale), love.graphics.getHeight()/(2*self.scale)
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.scale(self.scale)
    love.graphics.translate(cx, cy)
    love.graphics.rotate(self.rot)
    love.graphics.translate(-self.pos.x, -self.pos.y)
    return self
end
Camera.detatch = function (self)
    love.graphics.pop()
    return self
end
Camera.draw = function (self, func)
    self:attach()
    func()
    self:detach()
end
```

To use it you can do something like `Camera:draw(World:draw())` in your `love.draw` call, where `World:draw()` could be any function that draws something to the screen.

You can download an updated version of my original project [here](https://copy.com/uTmUCRkIhrQeqr2g).